# Is it possible to split one camera stream into different steams in real time?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax, firebase-mlkit

Is it possible to split one camera stream into different steams in real time?

1. For face recognition using the Firebase ML Kit
2. For recording the video

Comment: Do you use CameraX's image analysis? https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/analyze You can perform different operations on the same frame.

Comment: If you are using CameraX, currently, concurrent ImageAnalysis and VideoCapture is only supported on LEVEL_3 devices and above. CameraX is working on that feature right now, but there is no ETA. To do this yourself, you will have to share the Preview stream and use it for both video and preview.